# How can I change textContent in DOM if object is declared and assigned

Tags: javascript, html, dom, element

right now this line of code shows whats in DOM

```
let scoreDisplay = document.querySelector('.score').textContent
```

but if i want to change the textContent it doesnt work, why?

```
scoreDisplay = "twenty five"
```

the change is visible only in console.log but not in DOM, how can i make it affect the DOM as well?

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the value of the variable, not of the element itself. Try modifying your code to

```
let scoreDisplay = document.querySelector('.score')
scoreDisplay.textContent = "twenty five"
```

or even as a one-liner:

```
document.querySelector('.score').textContent= "twenty five"
```